# How to disable ESLint rule for whole TypeScript project using ts-standard?

Tags: typescript, eslint, standardjs

In my TypeScript project I am using the node modules "typescript" and "ts-standard". As IDE I am using Visual Studio Code with the "StandardJS - JavaScript Standard Style" extension. In its settings "Engine" is set to "ts-standard".

To disable a certain ESLint rule for one line I could write `/* eslint-disable-next-line padded-blocks */` right above that line.

To disable a certain ESLint rule for one file I could write `/* eslint-disable padded-blocks */` at the top of the file.

How do I disable a certain ESLint rule for the whole project/package/workspace?

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

[Standard.js](https://standardjs.com/), and consequently [ts-standard](https://github.com/standard/ts-standard), does not allow configuration of rules out-of-the-box:

> ### I disagree with rule X, can you change it?
>
> No. [...]

– [Standard.js](https://standardjs.com/index.html#i-disagree-with-rule-x-can-you-change-it)

> ### Please change X rule
>
> This project has no control over the rules implemented, as such this project cannot change any of the rules that have been configured. If you want to discuss the rules, please visit the rules configuration repo [`eslint-config-standard-with-typescript`](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript).
>
> ### Why
>
> This utility was designed to be the [`standard`](https://github.com/standard/standard) equivalent for typescript. Underneath the hood, this utility uses the same [`standard-engine`](https://github.com/standard/standard-engine) and combines that engine with the official [`eslint-config-standard-with-typescript`](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript) ruleset.

– [ts-standard](https://github.com/standard/ts-standard#-please-change-x-rule)

## Solution

The documentation above, however, does detail how you could get the ability to configure the rules:

> You can also choose to just use [`eslint`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint) with the [`eslint-config-standard-with-typescript`](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript) shareable config instead and achieve the same results as this project. But `ts-standard` saves you from having to manually install all the extra dependencies and may reduce configuration overhead.

– [ts-standard](https://github.com/standard/ts-standard#-why)

So what you must do is:

1. Uninstall `ts-standard`.
2. Install [`eslint-config-standard-with-typescript`](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript), along with its peer dependencies:

   - [`eslint`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint)
   - [`@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin)
   - [`eslint-plugin-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-promise)
   - [`eslint-plugin-import`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import)
   - [`eslint-plugin-n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-n)
3. Configure ESLint, extending the configuration provided by `eslint-config-standard-with-typescript`, in an [ESLint configuration file](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files). An example, in an `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'standard-with-typescript',
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json'
  }
}
```

At this point, you can now specify your own rules in the ESLint configuration file, with the [`rules` key](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/rules#using-configuration-files). An example, continuing from the previous:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'standard-with-typescript',
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json'
  },
  rules: {
    'padded-blocks': 'off'
  }
}
```